# How to find the Default Activity Class Name?

Tags: android, facebook-login

I have purchased this app from Codecanyon but the documentation is not so much clear. My question is how could I find the Default Activity Class Name?
This is my androidmanifest.xml file. I am unable to figure out the Launcher activity. I need this for FB login API integration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.mehar.Consol">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

    <dist:module dist:instant="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:name=".Presentation.ui.activities.impl.WalletActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Presentation.ui.activities.impl.ProductDescriptionActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Presentation.ui.activities.impl.ResetPasswordActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Presentation.ui.activities.impl.MyBidsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Presentation.ui.activities.impl.SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Presentation.ui.activities.impl.ProductReviewActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Presentation.ui.activities.impl.AccountInfoActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Presentation.ui.activities.impl.StripePaymentActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Presentation.ui.activities.impl.SellerShopActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Presentation.ui.activities.impl.PaymentActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Presentation.ui.activities.impl.RegisterActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Presentation.ui.activities.impl.ShippingActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Presentation.ui.activities.impl.PurchaseHistoryDetailsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Presentation.ui.activities.impl.PurchaseHistoryActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Presentation.ui.activities.impl.WishlistActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Presentation.ui.activities.impl.BuyingOptionsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Presentation.ui.activities.impl.PolicyViewActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Presentation.ui.activities.impl.ProductDetailsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Presentation.ui.activities.impl.SubCategoryActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Presentation.ui.activities.impl.ProductListingActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Presentation.ui.activities.impl.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Presentation.ui.activities.impl.LoginActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.braintreepayments.api.BraintreeBrowserSwitchActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="${applicationId}.braintree" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please help me by telling the Default Activity Class Name?

Comment: SplashActivity is your Launcher activity. kindly check which activity start from SplashActivity using Intent that is your Default activity.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "Default Activity"?

Answer (score 1):

```
<activity android:name=".Presentation.ui.activities.impl.SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The `<activity></activity>` tag that has this line:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

is your launcher activity, so it is SplashActivity. If you want to find what activity opens from this activity you need to check the code. Search for something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, OtherActivity.class;
startActivity(intent);
```

or

```
startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, OtherActivity.class));
```

There are many options to start a new activity but it should look like this. If you have any other questions just ask in the comments below.